# JQuery ajax call never triggers error handler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I have an Ajax call that is called once and then it calls itself recursively in order to manage a newsletter send job (the send is managed by the send.php script). The call works pretty well (generally for the first 15-20 mins it goes well), the only problem is that **sometime the call never returns but it does not trigger the error function that you can see inside the ajax call**. Infact the alert is never called and the "SEND ERROR!!" message is never displayed. What can be the problem?

The following is the interested function:

```
    function _ajax_send(id_send, curr_index)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/send.php",
            data: { id: id_send, index: curr_index },
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            global: true,
            timeout: 130000,
            erorr: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("SEND ERROR!!");
                setTimeout(function(){ _ajax_send(<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>, Number(sent)); }, 3000);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.result) {
                    if(!data.completed)
                    {
                        calls = calls + 1;
                        _ajax_send(id_send, data.curr_index);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Logic Error. Cause: " + data.error);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you very much for any help ;)

Comment: Could it be the fact that it's called `error`, not `erorr` ?

Comment: I made a change in order to see whether this is the problem or not. In the meantime write it as an answer so I can give you a + 1 and Solved if you are correct! ;)